# How to get EF Objects to work in the WCFTestClient

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, wcf-client

I have a solution that has some EF objects.  I want to pass them down to the client.

When I try to test this in the WCFTestClient.exe I get this error on my objects:

"This operation is not supported in the wcf test client"

Is there a way to set things up so I can pass my Entity objects down to the client or am I going to have to make a separate class that duplicates everything.

Vaccano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with the WCFTestClient.  I am researching some other clients to see if they will do it (ie WCFStorm)

Answer (score 1):

Try out SOA Cleaner, can be found at http://xyrow.com, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

why not just create your own client? Its only 10-15 minutes of coding (if that)